# Python plot with unique colors for more than 10 lines

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot the line graph with around `15` to `50` items, colors are repeating that makes the graph not usable.

I have tried the answers from several method in the answers of a similar question like numpy, random.

However, i am unable to find a easy way to do this .

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import pandas as pd
import random
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import matplotlib.dates as dates
import matplotlib.colors as colors
import numpy as np

df2=pd.read_csv("Portperfdetails.csv")
df3 = df2.drop(df2.index[0])
df3['DATETIME'] = pd.to_datetime(df3['DATETIME'])
portname=list(dict.fromkeys(df3['PORT_NAME']))
for i in range(len(portname)):
    X = []
    Y = []
    X = list(df3.loc[df3['PORT_NAME'] == '%s' % portname[i]]['DATETIME'])
    Y = list(df3.loc[df3['PORT_NAME'] == '%s' % portname[i]]['TOTAL_MBYTES'])
    ax = plt.axes()
    ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(dates.HourLocator(interval=4))  # every 4 hours
    ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(dates.DateFormatter('%H:%M'))  # hours and minutes
    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(dates.DayLocator(interval=1))  # every day
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(dates.DateFormatter('\n%d-%m-%Y'))
    for i in range(len(Y)):
        Y[i] = int(Y[i])
    num_plots = 20
    plt.plot(X, Y)
    plt.ylabel('Port throughput')
    plt.xlabel('Time')
    plt.savefig('example.png')
```

[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3FP9z.png)

Comment: Most of the methods which i tried doesn't reflect a unique colors even though it's random. if plot colors are same my graph doesn't make any sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll use a toy example since I do not have access to your data (`df3`).

I adapted this directly from the [List of named colors example](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/color/named_colors.html#sphx-glr-gallery-color-named-colors-py) in the Matplotlib Gallery. The idea is to iterate over color names along with each *line* that is being plotted and use the color name to specify the color for each line.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as colors
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
lotsa_colors = colors.get_named_colors_mapping()
for cname,i in zip(lotsa_colors,range(50)):
    y = [n for n in range(i,i+10)]
    #print(cname,lotsa_colors[name])
    ax.plot(y,color=lotsa_colors[cname])

plt.show()
#plt.close()
```

---

Looks like there are 1163 color names and 1105 unique colors

```
len(set(lotsa_colors.values()))
```

If you wanted to you could randomize the color names.

```
import random
lotsa_colors = colors.get_named_colors_mapping()
lotsa_colors = list(lotsa_colors.keys())
random.shuffle(lotsa_colors)
```

Comment: get_named_colors_mapping() works for me as long it gives a unique color for each plot